# Vagrant - Use Hyper V on a different machine

Tags: vagrant, hyper-v

I am new to Vagrant and I am trying to get it to use a host which is on a different machine.

Every time I run the Vagrant Up command it looks for the Hyper-V role on the current machine.

Is there any way to point it at a different host?  I've looked at the docs but can't seem to find how to do this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently Vagrant doesn't support remote Hyper-V virtual machines.

According to Vagrant lead developer, it's *not something they're targeting right now*:

https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/3663

Comment: That's a real shame. :(